# Android user activity log

Tags: android, android-activity, process, nsrunningapplication

I want to make an android service that will keep running in the background and track which apps the user has used and how many times he used the app. e.g

```
AppName  : Start Time : Stop Time    
WhatsApp :10:30 AM    : 10:50 AM
Chrome   :12:00 PM    : 01:00 PM
```

Comment: Feel free to do that. Who stops you?

Comment: the problem is, i am unable to catch all application lunching and close event to track running time. I want same statistics as in Setting->Apps->running Apps->[any app]. that showing running time. i want same thing in my service.